# Select Datetime's of every pair of 2 rows in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I've got the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `playerjoins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `globalId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `serverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `playerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `globalId` (`globalId`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `serverId` (`serverId`),
  KEY `playerId` (`playerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `playerjoins_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`serverId`) REFERENCES `servers` (`serverId`),
  CONSTRAINT `playerjoins_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`playerId`) REFERENCES `players` (`playerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64983 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `playerleaves` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `globalId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `serverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `playerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `globalId` (`globalId`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `serverId` (`serverId`),
  KEY `playerId` (`playerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `playerleaves_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`serverId`) REFERENCES `servers` (`serverId`),
  CONSTRAINT `playerleaves_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`playerId`) REFERENCES `players` (`playerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45676 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And, to start off, I want to select every pair of rows, ordered by `date ASC, globalId ASC`.

How will I be able to do that query? Furthermore, for information, I want to use it to be able to obtain (psuedo-code) `row1.datetime, row2.datetime` and use that again somewhere else in my query.

**Example data, using some more abstract object notation:**

Assume the following is the result data of a specific player:

- Playerjoin_1
- Playerleave_1
- Playerjoin_2
- Playerleave_2

Then I'd want to create the following rows as output of the (sub)query:

- (Playerjoin_1, Playerleave_1)
- (Playerjoin_2, Playerleave_2)

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "I want to select every pair of rows"? :O

Comment: @Manu Clarified it in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you any closer?

```
SELECT * FROM
playerjoins pj
LEFT JOIN
playerleaves pl
ON( pj.playerId = pl.playerId AND pj.serverId = pl.serverId AND pj.date <= pl.date )
GROUP BY pj.playerId, pj.serverId;
```

This would give you arbitrary row for the playerleaves table.
Given the current db structure, you will need to write a stored procedure, that obviously more work than a single query.

What I suggest is that you change the db structure( if possible ).

My suggestion is that you get rid of the `playerleaves` table and in the `playerjoins` table add the columns for leaveDate.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: pj.date should be <= than pl.date.

Comment: That's a tricky question. It does get me somewhat closer, the problem is that the `<=` 'arbitrarily' matches. It doesn't take the next date in line.

Comment: Yes @skiwi.. It will match arbitrarily. I will update the answer. Achieving what you desire is not possible with a single query.